# session State data in AWS DynamoDb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, session-state

I am not able to find many resources to help me.

I am trying to migrate asp.net session state form SQL to DynamoDB.

What is the best way to get rid of unused session data (expire them) and delete expired session. something like SQL stored proc

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these directions:

> The AWS SDK for .NET includes AWS.SessionProvider.dll, which contains
>   an ASP.NET session state provider. Also included is the
>   AmazonDynamoDBSessionProviderSample sample, which demonstrates how to
>   use Amazon DynamoDB as a session-state provider.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-dynamodb-session.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt TTL feature of DynamoDb to achieve this. You can set the TTL column and expiry in epoch time, and the data will be deleted by DynamoDb itself.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html